# Overflow hidden is making page to jump on top

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I am using antD in my react project.

while opening a model or drawer it is adding overflow hidden in the body.

Which leads to jumping my page to top.

I tried lot of things,

```
height: auto
```

removing overflow from html

but none of the solutions is working fine for me

Comment: why you want to add overflow hidden?
if you only want to add overflow hidden to prevent page scroll when model opens try putting a transparent element of width:100% and height:100vh behind model
that will stop page from scrolling

Comment: @DesiMulga I am not adding it, it's the library which I am using antd doing it programmatically to the body directly as style. Even if I remove it after appearing the model from body programmatically it has been already jumped!

Comment: Check out my ans below
let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

one hack could be get scrollTop of body before opening model and then scroll to it after model opens

```
let bodyScrollTop=document.body.scrollTop;
// open model here
document.body.scrollTop=bodyScrollTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add initial value to body:

```
body {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!
Regards,